# background color works in index.html but not user-interface.css

Tags: html, css

In the index.html file I am able to do this an it works as designed:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <body style="background-color: #A8E4A0;">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Demo</title>
```

My partner would like to keep the background-color in our css file  user-interface.css.  Which makes sense to me but it is not working as I would expect.
When I enter the background-color it doesn't show up and leaves my background-color as white.
What am I missing?

```
* Universal Settings */
    .body{ 
            background-color : AE8E4A0;
            font-family: Arial;
    }
    /* Search bar */
    .heading {
            font-size: 30px;
            padding: 16px 0;
            color: #444;
            text-align: center;
    }/*Container*/`enter code here`
```

Thanks
Scott

Comment: you miss the # in front of the color in your css :)

Comment: Your HTML should follow the basic convention of proper open & close tags 
<html><head> meta tage an titles are in heae </head><body> ... </body></html>

Comment: The `link`, `meta` and `title` tags should only be included in the `head`. The `body` tag should have `html` as its only parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added to CSS background-color: #A8E4A0; and verified the link in my htlm was correct

Answer (score 2):

You have a minor error on your code. You should not put the dot (.) in front of body as it is not a class name, it's an element. Same for the heading. So your code should be like:

```css
/* Universal Settings */
    body{ 
            background-color : #AE8E4A0;
            font-family: Arial;
    }
    /* Search bar */
    heading {
            font-size: 30px;
            padding: 16px 0;
            color: #444;
            text-align: center;
    }/*Container*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link href="cssfilename.css">
    <body style="background-color: #A8E4A0;">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Demo</title>
```

Also, you would need to link your CSS to your HTML file. Not that the "cssfilename.css" need to be replaced by the filename of your css file, and they need to be in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />    
    <title>My first Website!</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #A8E4A0;
            font-family: arial;
        } 
        p {
            color: green;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is a paragraph!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want the style in a seperate .css file, try this:

```css
/* style.css */

/* Needs to be in the same folder/directory as the .html file is. */

body {
    background-color: #A8E4A0;
    font-family: arial;
} 

p {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<!-- Index.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
     <meta charset="UTF-8" />    
     <title>My first Website!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is a paragraph!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The background-color is still not working in CSS  Universal Settings */
user-interface.css                                                                                               body{ 
        background-color: A8E4A0;
        font-family: Arial;
}

Comment: This should not solve the problem. I was only giving you a tip on the readability of the markup. Also, this is a hexadecimal aka base16 code, so you need to type #A8E4A0.

Comment: I updated my post, it should really be solved now.